# DirectX10 swapchain and device point to 0x00000000 (causing runtime error) (c++)

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-2010, directx

Ok, i followed [this tutorial](http://www.directxtutorial.com/Tutorial10/B-Direct3DBasics/dx10B1.aspx) (code is down below on the page, just top of the picture you can click on show code) about DX10 and c++
basically the code is like

```
// include and stuff
ID3D10Device* device;  // adding = NULL wont change problem
ID3D10RenderTargetView* rtv;
IDXGISwapChain* swapchain;
// function predecs, winmain, winproc
// winmain calls initD3D(hWnd) just before entering msg loop

void initD3D(HWND hWnd){
    DXGI_SWAP_CHAIN_DESC scd; // creates struct for swap chain info
    ZeroMemory(&scd, sizeof(DXGI_SWAP_CHAIN_DESC)); // clear the struct for use

    scd.BufferCount = 1; // create two buffers one front buffer one back buffer
    scd.BufferDesc.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_B8G8R8A8_UNORM; // use 32-bit color
    scd.BufferUsage = DXGI_USAGE_RENDER_TARGET_OUTPUT; // tell how chain is to be used
    scd.OutputWindow = hWnd; // set window to be used by d3d
    scd.SampleDesc.Count = 1; // set level of multi sampling
    scd.SampleDesc.Quality = 0; // set quality of multisampling
        scd.Windowed = true; // set to windowed or fullscreen

    D3D10CreateDeviceAndSwapChain(NULL, D3D10_DRIVER_TYPE_HARDWARE,
                                  NULL, 0, D3D10_SDK_VERSION, &scd,
                                  &swapchain, &device);
    // get the adress of the backbuffer and use it to create the render target
    ID3D10Texture2D* pBackBuffer;
        // AND HERE (NEXT LINE) THE ERROR OCCURS
    swapchain->GetBuffer(0, __uuidof(ID3D10Texture2D), (LPVOID*)&pBackBuffer);
        // on runtime debugger tells me swapchain value is 0x00000000
        // why does it point to nowhere?

    device->CreateRenderTargetView(pBackBuffer, NULL, &rtv);
    pBackBuffer->Release();

    // set the render target as the back buffer
    device->OMSetRenderTargets(1, &rtv, NULL);

    D3D10_VIEWPORT viewport; // create a struct to hold the viewport data

    ZeroMemory(&viewport, sizeof(D3D10_VIEWPORT)); // clear the struct
    //viewport.stuff

    device->RSSetViewports(1, &viewport); //set the viewport
```

}

i left out the unnecessary code, I think you can either figure it out or follow the link if you really need the full code, I want to focus on the main problem ;)

so as stated in the code my debugger tells me that `swapchain` points to 0x00000000 looking through the values i found out that its the same with `device` also poinmts to 0x00000000.
Message is:

```
First-chance exception at 0x........ in bla.exe: 0x........: Access violation reading location 0x00000000
```

i looked over the whole code, have no idea what might be the problem.

could it be a hardware related problem?
I am on a Thinkpad T510 with two graphics chips (one intel and one nVidia), using the nVidia chips as default causes Visual Studio to crash.

i have no idea what else might be the problem, because the tutorial states that the code will run :)
i know that there is another topic with a very very related problem, but as far as i understand its not the same. (and the answer the author gave himself doesn't solve my problem)

edit: i just read debug output and it seems that a ****load of *.dlls couldn't be loaded
btw I am using the x86 libs of DX SDK

snippet:

```
'AnotherWindowsApp.exe': Loaded 'E:\visual studio 2010 Projects\AnotherWindowsApp\Debug\AnotherWindowsApp.exe', Symbols loaded.
'AnotherWindowsApp.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ntdll.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'AnotherWindowsApp.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\kernel32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'AnotherWindowsApp.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\KernelBase.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
[...]
'AnotherWindowsApp.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\nvinit.dll', Binary was not built with debug information.
'AnotherWindowsApp.exe': Loaded 'C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\coprocmanager\detoured.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'AnotherWindowsApp.exe': Loaded 'C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\coprocmanager\Nvd3d9wrap.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
[...]
'AnotherWindowsApp.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\d3d9.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'AnotherWindowsApp.exe': Loaded 'C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\coprocmanager\nvdxgiwrap.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'AnotherWindowsApp.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\d3d11.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
[...]
'AnotherWindowsApp.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\igd10umd32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
First-chance exception at 0x7623b727 in AnotherWindowsApp.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: _com_error at memory location 0x0045f06c..
First-chance exception at 0x7623b727 in AnotherWindowsApp.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: _com_error at memory location 0x0045ef90..
First-chance exception at 0x7623b727 in AnotherWindowsApp.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: _com_error at memory location 0x0045f0e0..
The thread 'Win32 Thread' (0x18b0) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 'Win32 Thread' (0x12dc) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 'Win32 Thread' (0x354) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 'UMDShimPresentThread' (0x1080) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
'AnotherWindowsApp.exe': Unloaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\nvwgf2um.dll'
'AnotherWindowsApp.exe': Unloaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\igd10umd32.dll'
First-chance exception at 0x01281758 in AnotherWindowsApp.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000000.
Unhandled exception at 0x01281758 in AnotherWindowsApp.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000000.
First-chance exception at 0x01281758 in AnotherWindowsApp.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000000.
Unhandled exception at 0x01281758 in AnotherWindowsApp.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000000.
The program '[5912] AnotherWindowsApp.exe: Native' has exited with code -1073741819 (0xc0000005).
```

Comment: You should check what error code is returned by the D3D10CreateDeviceAndSwapChain function.

Comment: @PetPaulsen: this is a valid answer to the question. the `D3D10CreateDeviceAndSwapChain()` call failed. so, you should post it as an answer.

Comment: I never did something related with DirectX, but locking at the docs, aren't you responsible for filling the DXGI_SWAP_CHAIN_DESC struct?

Comment: i dont known why i just copy and pasted the whole code from the website... and now it works. only difference is, that this time i included the x64 libs along with the x86 libs from the DX SDK... edit: even without the x64 libs it works... now everything is on error-lookup.

Comment: One thing thats different is the Buffer Format. The tutorial uses DXGI_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM but you used DXGI_FORMAT_B8G8R8A8_UNORM.

Comment: i hate intelli sense now :) seriously, i compared everything twice just now, even that line, but i haven't seen that, many many thanks. please reedit your answer below, i wanna accept something ;)

Comment: Im glad I could help you. I updated may answer, so you can accept :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you should check what error code is returned by the D3D10CreateDeviceAndSwapChain function. Compare the error code with the ones on [this site](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb205278%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to get a first idea, what may have gone wrong.

'swapchain' and 'device' are set to zero (0x00000000), when the D3D10CreateDeviceAndSwapChain  function wasn't successful.

Second, according to the [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb173075%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) the DXGI_SWAP_CHAIN_DESC struct is an 'in' parameter.
Probably this causes your error.

**Update** (Based on the comments):
One thing thats different to the tutorial is the Buffer Format. The tutorial uses DXGI_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM but you used DXGI_FORMAT_B8G8R8A8_UNORM.

Comment: I think it's just ommitted in the snippet: `some stuff setting scd.parameters follows here`. However, wrong parameters here are the most likely cause so it would be nice to see them.

Comment: as written in the comments (in the code), it is actually in the code, but for me took away the focus from the problem, so i left it out. parameters are exactly like above i will reedit it into above code, wasnt aware that it could be so related to the problem

Comment: yeah i know, i really try to understand directX, so i create a load of comments to ask myself what i do there. if they are too annoying i can edit them out

Comment: ok, i simply added put the output of D3D10CreateStuff in an HRESULT (as i said in antoher comment below) and added `if(FAILED(hr)) { return; }`  and now i am kicked out excactly there and runtime fails to destroy the swapchain (how should it, never has been there). so many thanks till now, but how do i solve this?

Comment: You wrote that you are using the intel chip as default. What happens when you switch to the NVidia chip? Maybe the intel chip doesn't support DX10. edit: just read your comment on another answer ... you already had that idea, I was too slow ...

Comment: biggest problem is, that visual studio crashes if i set nVidia chip globally default, so i have to use an exception in windows to always use Intel Chip for VStudio :/ but result is the same, doesn't matter if i run the program through VStudio or run the exe directly from folder, even if I specify that the nVidia chip has to be used for that program.

Answer (score 0):

Consider turning on the D3D debug output, it will surely tell you what went wrong in `D3D10CreateDeviceAndSwapChain`.

Comment: i added `HRESULT hr = ` in front of `D3D10CreateDevice` but if i try to add `if(FAILED(hr)) throw GXVideoException(L"Problems retrieving directX device");` i get `GXVideoException: identiefier not found` which include am I missing here? edit: i am stupid ... sorry ... have no try catch block, so i might just add one

Answer (score 0):

This occurs because `D3D10CreateDeviceAndSwapChain` fails. You didn't check the return code. You attempted to create a D3D10 hardware device but may not be running with D3D10-level graphics hardware, for example. Use the Direct3D debug output to tell you what the error was.

Comment: as i stated i run on a dual graphics card system, what might be the problem. the 3D chip is a NVIDIA® Quadro® NVS3100M which is capable of DX10, but i think the program tries to run on the Intel Adapter